# react snap and skipThirdPartyRequests

Tags: reactjs, npm

I setted skipThirdPartyRequests to true but react-snap has blocked all requests. I know it's normal behaviour but I have own API and haven't idea how I can send API requests to the same host (localhost:45678) that is used by react-snap when prerendering is executing. So I sent requests in prerendering stage to production domain but after enabling skipThirdPartyRequests these requests is being blocked. I need skipThirdPartyRequests for disabling Google Analytics and other services.

Are there ideas how I can communicate with own API in prerendering stage with enabled skipThirdPartyRequests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. We can up own express server and call `run` function of react-snap with options `{..., externalServer: true, port: /*port of your server*/}`, then react-snap will not start own server and will just send requests to `localhost:{port}`. In our express server we can use proxy middleware `http-proxy-middleware` for proxying react-snap`s requests to real backend.

My fragment code:

```
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const fallback = require("express-history-api-fallback");
const serveStatic = require("serve-static");
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const {run} = require("react-snap");


let general = {
    "port": 45678,
    "externalServer": true,
    "skipThirdPartyRequests": true,
    "puppeteerArgs": [
        "--no-sandbox",
        "--disable-setuid-sandbox"
    ],
    source: "build",
    publicPath: '/'

};

const startServer = options => {
    const sourceDir = path.normalize(`${process.cwd()}/${options.source}`);
    const app = express()
        .use(proxy('/socket.io', { target: process.env.PRERENDERING_URI, changeOrigin: true, ws: true }))
        .use(options.publicPath, serveStatic(sourceDir))
        .use(fallback("200.html", { root: sourceDir }));

    const server = http.createServer(app);
    server.listen(options.port);
    return server;
};

let server = startServer(general);

Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => run({
        ...general,
        destination: "build/desktop",
        fixWebpackChunksIssue: false,
        userAgent: 'ReactSnap',
        "viewport": {
            "width": 1600,
            "height": 1200

        },
    }))
    .catch(console.error)
    .then(() => {
        server.close()
    });
```